# Finding if domain name is already registered?

Tags: api, domain-name

<del>Hi, Is there any API to lookup if a given domain name is already registerd by somebody and get alternative (auto suggested available domain names)?</del>

EDIT:- I think the thing I need is called domain-search not the lookup :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your support. I've found a service by [domaintools.com](http://www.domaintools.com) called [whoisapi](http://xml-api.domaintools.com/api23.html). You can query available domain names and other information by sending an xml request to their servers.

Answer (score 4):

I've written a whois for PHP, Perl, VB and C# all using a trick that queries `'{domain}.whois-servers.net'`.

It works well for all but the obscure domains that require registration (and usually fees) such as tonga .tv or .pro domains.

- [PHP Whois](http://www.shrinkrays.net/code-snippets/archive/php.aspx) (version 3.x but should still work)
- [C# Whois](http://www.shrinkrays.net/code-snippets/csharp/network-tools-source.aspx)
- [COM Whois (DLL only, I lost the source)](http://www.shrinkrays.net/tools/com-component-downloads.aspx)

[This page](http://www.shrinkrays.net/tools/network-tools.aspx) shows it in action. You can do some simple string matching to check if a domain is registered or not based on the result you get back.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [whois](http://www.whois.net/)... and for auto-suggestion, there is the domain service at [1&1](http://order.1and1.com/).

Comment: Isn't there something that I can directly call from C# code like web-service?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mashape.com/apis/Name+Toolkit#Get-domain-suggestions - Advanced domain name suggestions and domain checking API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use http://whois.domaintools.com/ to get the information. Send a web request as http://whois.domaintools.com/example.com and it will return the information of example.com. But you need to parse the response to filter the required information.

Comment: I don't want to get into that parsing thing. Anything simple please?

Comment: There's no universal API as far as I know, you would have to create one yourself. If you then decide to parse the web page, use HtmlAgilityPack (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

http://whois.bw.org/ is very good. does suggestions and such.

Answer (score 0):

I want an api that I can call from my code or pages. The [XML API](http://xml-api.domaintools.com/) on www.domaintools.com seems like the thing that I need. I'm looking into it.